# How to assign static IP to Ubuntu Server (VirtualBox)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

Please see my setup here:

NAT is set up here:

[image]

Host-only adapter is enabled here:

[image]

network for virtual box is configured here:

[image]

then I set up interface on the server like this:

[image]

then I run `sudo netplan apply` and I should be all set. I can ping myself on the server:

[image]

but can't ping the server from my local computer:

[image]

Hence the network isn't actually connected to the Internet.
What am I doing wrong here ?

**update:**

network connection is now set to "bridged":

[image]

Comment: You can either set the network connection to Bridged or set port forwarding on host computer.

Comment: I've set connection to "bridged" but it didn't help.

Comment: If you did so, your IP address should change and should be in the same network as hosted computer. Is that right ?

Comment: Well ... no, because I assigned static IP of 192.168.56.102 to the server should share the name network with the host. So the IP of the server is unchanged. But I need the server to have access to the Internet from host. Bridged connection is set but didn't make difference to the virtual machine.

Comment: I know this setup should work hence I created a thread here.

Comment: What IP does have your host PC ?

Comment: It's 192.168.1.229. Though I'm further now. Machines can ping each other now but the server still doesn't have access to the Internet through host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106468/discussion-between-john-ronald-and-mr-incredible).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **Yes** if you assign a static ip from your router for your virtual box virtual machine. (This need specific ip address from your local router).

The answer is **No** if you aren't assign a static ip from your router for your virtual box virtual machine.

***If not how can we access the virtual machine via our laptop terminal ?***

**This is the method how to do that !**

***Keep in mind this is temporary method and all settings are reset after you restart the virtual machine . This will also enable internet access on your virtual box sever.***

According to your question ,

**First configure NAT (Network Address Translation) setting for Network Adapter 1**

[image: NAT Configuration]

**Then configure Host-only Adapter setting for Network Adapter 2**

[image: Host-only Adapter configuration]

**After that manual IP address assignment**

[image: Manual ip address assignment]

**Here don't enable the DHCP server as below**

[image]

**These are the settings for your server virtual machine hardware *(assume that your are using a Ubuntu server virtual machine)* !**

After that install the Ubuntu server on the *virtual hard disk* ...

After you *log on* to the Ubuntu server *(i think you provided administrative credentials )* , you have to do the followings.

First issue the following command to see the ip settings assigned for network adapters on the virtual Ubuntu server

```
 ubuntu@vagrant:~$ ifconfig
```

*On my test server there are eth0 , eth1 network interface cards , I have selected eth1 for this because eth0 is already assigned with an ip address by system default.*

On Ubuntu server switch to the root user as ,

```
 ubuntu@vagrant:~$ sudo -i
```

Then the appear root user prompt as below ,

```
 root@vagrant:~#
```

Then issue the following command

```
 root@vagrant:~# ifconfig eth1 192.168.188.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Once you done this exit from the root user by typing *exit*

**Here don't turn off the virtual machine !**

Then minimize the virtual machine and fireup a local terminal

After that issue *ifconfig* on the local terminal . Here you can see the various network adapters including the host only adaptor.

Then try to ping the ip address of the virtual machine as below

```
user@user-laptop:~$ ping 192.168.188.101
```

If this ping is success you can now ssh to the your virtual Ubuntu server as below

```
user@user-laptop:~ ssh ubuntu@192.168.188.101
```

Here you can provide the virtual server password .

So I think this method is worked for you if you are interested .